# How to declare a C nested struct in a Java class

Tags: java, struct, nested, javolution

I'm trying to map a c struct to a Java class. Everything works fine so far but I don't know how to map a struct which has another struct as a member.

In the Struct class javadoc there is an example of a struct containing a pointer to the same struct (using the class Reference32) but it is not what I need.

I can't find further documentation about how to achieve this.

This is a simplified example:

```
// c types --------------------------------

enum Enum16{VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3};

struct t_composite {
   int number;
   char text[20];
   };

struct t_demo {
   char _char2[2];        
   char _char14[14];      
   int _int;
   float _float;
   double _double;
   enum Enum16 enum16;
   struct t_composite _otherStruct;
   };

// Java class -------------------------

public class Composite extends Struct {

public final Signed32 number = new Signed32();
public final UTF8String text = new UTF8String(20);
// ...
}

public class Demo extends Struct {

public enum EnumValues {
    VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3
};

public final UTF8String _char2 = new UTF8String(2);
public final UTF8String _char15 = new UTF8String(14);
public final Signed32 _int = new Signed32();
public final Float32 _float = new Float32();
public final Float64 _double = new Float64();
public final Enum32<EnumValues> _enum32 = new Enum32<EnumValues>(EnumValues.values());
//  public final Reference32<Composite> _otherStruct = new Reference32<Composite>();  // incorrect
public final Composite _otherStruct = new Composite(); // doesn't work

// ....
}
```

---

Variable "_otherStruct" is never filled in Java. I've tried defining the java variable as a Composite class instead of Reference32 but it didn't do the trick.

How is the right way of doing this?

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**

As the main developer Jean-Marie Dautelle pointed to me, this is fully supported through the use of the inner method:

```
public final Composite _otherStruct = inner(new Composite());
```

That works perfectly

Comment: Your `public final Composite _otherStruct = new Composite();` should work at least that your `Composite` class has a different constructor than default.

Comment: Basically, in Java you can't include a struct(class) "inline" in another struct(class) declaration like you can in C.  You have to use a pointer(reference).  This is one of the shortcomings of Java (though it avoids a lot of problems that would occur otherwise).

Comment: And as Luiggi says that assignment/initialization should work.  You should figure out what's not working there.